# Github include md files in README.md?

Tags: github, markdown, readme

Is there a way in [Github](https://github.com/) to include md files in for example the README.md?

```
# Headline

Text

[include](File:load_another_md_file_here.md)
```

It should not link to the file, it should load the contents from it, like PHP include / file_get_contents.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That does not seem to be possible, especially when considering [`github/markup#346`](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/346) and [`github/markup#172`](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/172#issuecomment-33241601).

No include directive is supported.

Comment: Thanks! I will do the workaround then, use Gulp Concat to merge the files into one before sent to Github.

Comment: Yeah, and this is very unlikely to change in the future. [Github doesn't provide this feature even for reStructuredText](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/172) (rst) which has include directive in the official language spec.

Answer (score 15):

Since it is not possible I just ended up placing a link as

```
[MY-LINK](../../SOME-OTHER-README.MD)
```

Comment: this is an answer: "is not possible", and proposes an alternative (not the best in my opinion, but it's fine)

Comment: Is there no solution yet?

Answer (score 11):

migrate your readme to a different file then construct your actual README however you like as a github action

EDIT: Here's a demo that you can build off of. This repo has a single github action that runs a script that dynamically builds the README.md based on the contents of the repository (to build a site map for the repo in the form of a table of contents): https://github.com/dmarx/bench-warmers

the workflow config:

```
name: update-readme

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      - name: Run the script
        run: python scripts/update_readme.py
      - name: Commit files
        run: |
          git config --local user.name "dmarx"
          git add README.md
          git commit -m "Updated TOC"
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          force: true
```

Here's the chunk of my update script that's relevant to you:

```
... # code that builds the object `toc_str`

# template readme
with open('README.stub') as f:
    readme_stub = f.read()

# simple replacement, use whatever stand-in value is useful for you.
readme = readme_stub.replace('{TOC}',toc_str)

with open('README.md','w') as f:
    f.write(readme)
```

Which assumes you have a file named `README.stub` which might look something like this:

```
# Title

some text

{TOC}

more text
```

Where `{TOC}` is the substitution target for our dynamic content.

Answer (score 10):

This is not the correct answer but a workaround for others who really want this.

It's possible to use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [Gulp Concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) to merge the files into one before they are sent to Github..

Answer (score 2):

Ruby gem [markdown_helper](https://rubygems.org/gems/markdown_helper) implements include files for GitHub flavored markdown (GFM).

Disclosure:  I wrote the gem.

Comment: Does this work when viewing the markdown file on Github itself?