# Github markdown load code block from a repo file

Tags: github, markdown

I want to add a JSON code block in my `README.md` and the code block needs to be loaded from the repo file.

E.g, is it possible to do the following?

````
```json
<<load data from res/data.json>>
```
````

where `res/data.json` is a file in the same repo? I know it is possible to have a hyperlink, but I want the JSON data to appear there directly without clicking on the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a way to do this, and while I agree with Chris' analysis, you might consider github actions as a possible work-around:

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/markdown-embed-code-from-file

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do with GitHub Flavored Markdown.

You could programmatically update your `README.md` and then commit the resulting file, though. The simplest solution would probably be to have a `README-top.md` containing everything up to ```` ```json ```` and a `README-bottom.md` containing ```` ``` ```` to the end of the file.

Then you could simply do something like

```
cat README-top.md res/data.json README-bottom.md > README.md
```

There are lots of other options, including fairly complex templating tools.

A [`pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) would let you automate this even further, updating your `README.md` every time you commit locally.

Comment: pre-commit hook is an interesting idea, but it is a client-side tool and I can't expect everyone on the project to be using those hooks (given that there is no way of enforcing client-side hooks for all members i.e, members need to download the client-side hooks separately and get it installed). 
The problem is I have multiple users contributing to the README each having their JSONs in a separate file and need to include that JSON in the README. I was hoping to have a foldable section (which is possible in Github using <details> tag)  and showing JSON in that section.

Comment: Then I think we're back to the first line of my answer: this isn't possible with GFM. It doesn't support any kind of logic, including "includes". Here is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35080160/354577) about including other Markdown files in a GitHub `README.md`.