# In Quarto, can I include a file and have it rendered as source code?

Tags: markdown, quarto

Is there a way in quarto to include a code snippet from another file and have it rendered as source code ?

Something like

`{{< include-as-code src/file.py >}}`

could embed the contents in a ```` ```python ```` block

A similar question is asked here [Github markdown load code block from a repo file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423819/github-markdown-load-code-block-from-a-repo-file)

Comment: What kind of source file you want to include? `R script` or `py script` or `qmd file`?

Comment: In the document I'm currently working on I would like to include julia source code and have it nicely formatted as just julia code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very quartolic, but since it is possible to use any pandoc filter in Quarto, you could use the [`include-code-files`](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/include-code-files) filter from the pandoc filter collection. Download the Lua code into a file and use it by adding

```
filters:
  - include-code-files.lua
```

in your YAML header.

Comment: The lua filter [`include-code-files`](https://github.com/b3/include-code-files#extension-for-quarto) can be installed as quarto extension now using `quarto add b3/include-code-files`. See the repo [readme](https://github.com/b3/include-code-files#installing-1) for more info.