# How create table with git commits in markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I want to create table with git commits in markdown but I don't know how create them. Note# The table needs full with the last commits or all.

Comment: can you give any example which type of table are you referring to?

Comment: I want to create a table when I do commit, in the readme include the new commit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, as mentioned in "[Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)"

> As the [official Markdown documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) (or [CommonMark](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/)) states, Markdown does not provide any special syntax for tables. Instead it uses HTML `<table>` syntax.
> But there exist Markdown syntax extensions which provide additional syntax for creating simple tables.

GFM (GitHub flavored Markdown) has [such an extension](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-).
So it depends first on the target environment which will have to display such a markdown table.

And you also need to limit/paginate your Git commit history (there can be *a lot of* commits in some repositories)

For instance, for the last 10 commits of the current branch:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "| Commit Hash | Commit Message |"
echo "|----|-----|"

# Get the last 10 Git commits
commits=$(git log -n 10 --pretty=format:"%h %s")

# Loop through each commit and display the hash and message
while read -r commit; do
  hash=$(echo "$commit" | awk '{print $1}')
  message=$(echo "$commit" | awk '{$1=""; print $0}')
  echo "| $hash | $message |"
done <<< "$commits"
```

Comment: Is correct, run in Git Bash but in the readme of github, no.
i want to found insert git log in the readme in gthub.

Comment: @JavierSantoyo Do yo mean the README of a Github repository of yours should include the last n commits, in a GitHub table, automatically refreshed whenever there is new commits? That would be tricky considering updating the README is in itself a commit. But I suppose not impossible through a GitHub Actions ([similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72918091/6309)).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to James George's repo:

[github-activity-readme](https://github.com/jamesgeorge007/github-activity-readme)

To understand more you can refer to: [GitHub Activity: video by codeSTACKr](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6d4KHSKqGk&t=460s)

> Here all the recent activities will be added automatically to readme.